# Failed when install iconv on ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, iconv

I am trying to install iconv (gem) on ruby 1.9.3 but it's fail when I run :

> gem install iconv

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/adhown/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... yes
checking for const of iconv() 2nd argument... no
creating Makefile

make
compiling iconv.c
In file included from iconv.c:21:0:
/home/adhown/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/st.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h" [-Wcpp]
iconv.c:22:20: fatal error: intern.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [iconv.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/adhown/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/iconv-0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/adhown/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/iconv-0.1/ext/iconv/gem_make.out
```

and I am install ruby with rbenv whether it is related?

anyone know how to fix it, thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to install Iconv? That's part of the standard library (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html) and usually you'd use String methods instead.

Comment: I am trying to install jekyll, and I got error when starting jekyll.the error is :
rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.

Comment: And "iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead" means that iconv is going away in favor of methods on String, there's no need to install Iconv by hand. You're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the iconv gem and use String#encode instead.

This will return a copy of the string in my_string_variable utf-8 encoded:

```
my_string_variable.encode('utf-8', {:invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => ''})
```

see: [Ruby-Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode)